# How to check $PS1 of all linux users

Tags: bash

I'd like to set the prompt for my users on all my servers if these users are using the default prompt and live it untouch if the user is using a prompts other than the default.

But the following always return an empty string:

```
$(su - ${user} -c "$(set | grep ^PS1)")
```

Here is the code in context:

```
set -uo pipefail
DefaultPs1=(\
      "" \
      "\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$" \
      "[\u@\h \W]\$" \
      )

log()
{

    logType=${1}
    msg=${2}
    echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") - ${msg}"
    [[ ${logType} == "e" ]] && exit 1

}

listUserWithBashShell()
{

    echo "$(grep /bin/bash /etc/passwd  | awk -F ":" '{print $1","$6}')"

}

  
for userAndHome in $(listUserWithBashShell)
do

    user=$(echo "$userAndHome" | awk -F "," '{print $1}')
    home=$(echo "$userAndHome" | awk -F "," '{print $2}')


    log i "user: ${user} has home ${home}\n"
    currentPS1=$(su - ${user} -c "$(set | grep ^PS1)")
    log i "$user current prompt PS1 = \"${currentPS1}\""
    userID=$(su - ${user} -c "/usr/bin/id -u")
    log i "$user ID is: ${userID}"

    if [[ " ${DefaultPs1[*]} " =~ " ${currentPS1} " ]]
    then
        log i "INFO - Prompt currently default for user ${user}"
        log i "PS1=${currentPS1}"
        if [[ "${userID}" -eq 0 ]]
        then
            newPS1=$(setPrompt root)
            log i "Set root Prompt ${newPS1}"
            printf '%s' "PS1=${newPS1}\n" >> ${home}/.bashrc
            
        else
            newPS1=$(setPrompt user)
            log i "Set user Prompt to ${newPS1}"
            printf '%s' "PS1='${newPS1}'" >> ${home}/.bashrc
        fi
    fi

done
```

Comment: Since it's in double-quotes, the `"$(set | grep ^PS1)"` part will be evaluated before being passed to `su` as an argument (where it'll be treated as a command to execute). I think you just need to remove the `$( )`. I'd also recommend running the script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), as it'll point out several other weird/possibly bad things.